# Find out what's hitting the CRM Organization.svc

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Saving a record in CRM is quick, but saving the same record through the Organization service is taking a lot longer. Is there a way to see logs for the Organization.svc, or see what requests are being made on it? There are other applications that may be using the Organization.svc.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to call Organization.svc and the time difference you are experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the hardest part for your application is building of a service proxy. So my question is - do you recreate and reopen connection to CRM Endpoint everytim you perform operation? In case yes - I would suggest store organizationservice proxy somewhere to use it in code.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you're performing multiple connections to CRM from your app?  By default, .net limits the number of concurrent connections you can have open at once.  If you're running a website, and 10 people make a request at once, the first 1 or 2 (can't remember the default) will perform their request, and the rest will queue up.

Also if you're not using CRM online, you can enable Server Side tracing: [CRM 2011 Diagnostic Tool](http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com)